# How to select all records that are 10 minutes within current timestamp in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have timestamps in a table column called "last_seen" like so:

```
2012-01-25 18:46:42
2012-01-23 08:19:04
2012-01-23 08:19:04

etc...
```

How can I get all records where the timestamp is within 10 minutes of the current timestamp (in the most efficient way)?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

The most efficient way would be to compare your timestamp (and only timestamp, without using any functions on it) to an expression that can be calculated as constant for every row, this way mysql can use index defined on your timestamp column.

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE last_seen >= NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE
```

You can always try `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` to see if an index can be used to find rows satisfying your WHERE condition without the need to check every row in the table.

Answer (score 7):

Your question asks for records within 10 minutes of the current timestamp, but I will take that to mean no more than ten minutes in the past (not the future):

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 
FROM table
WHERE DATE_ADD(last_seen, INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) >= NOW();
```

This adds 10 minutes to `last_seen` and compares that against the current time. If the value is greater, `last_seen` is less than ten minutes ago.

See the [documentation on `DATE_ADD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) for an explanation of how it is used.

Comment: This fails as 'the most efficient' way.

Answer (score 2):

In case the method didn't work for some.

The 'where' condition in answers above didn't work for me until i added the timestamp column inside date() function (suggested by [@karam qubsi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2737574/karam-qubsi)) :

> SELECT * FROM myTable
>
> WHERE **date(last_seen)** >= NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE

Only then i started getting correct results.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wanting to extend the question beyond just one table and find any entries in any table in a database with date_modified within the last (say) 5 minutes, try this script.

Adjust the entries for database (I used a database called mgmt2go) and save the file below to an executable .sql file.

Adapt as you want for your situation, but if you only change the database setting, it will do the same for your database.

I run this SQL script from a command line and output the results to a file so I can refer to the output when I am debugging a system that writes all settings to a MySQL (actually MariaDB) database.  I needed to figure out what was being affected when i made changes through the system user interface.

```
# For this setup, it is best to send the output to a file
# and then read the file to see what records in what tables are found
# Save this file as list_tables.sql (or whatever you want to save it as)
# and use it by entering, at the CLI
# mysql --user=UserName --password=UserPassword -vv 2>&1 < path_to_executable_file/list_tables.sql > path_to_output_file/test.output.txt
# If you want the filename to include the time period, 
# concatentate the bash date function with the filename 
# ie: "mgmt2goDbaseChangesSince_"$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S --date -'5 min')  
# so the full sql comand would now look like
# mysql --user=UserName --password=UserPassword -vv 2>&1 < path_to_executable_file/list_tables.sql > "path_to_output_file/mgmt2goDbaseChangesFrom_"$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S --date -'5 min')"_to_"$(date +%H:%M:%S)


# Set the delimeter so you can distingish the delimiter surrounding the Procedure 
# (as an intact entity to be passed to the server)
# from the statements inside the Procedure calls
DELIMITER $$

# In case a previous script run created the procedure, 
# delete it before running this script again
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `mgmt2go`.rc_list_tables_procedure$$

# Create a procedure to identify all the tables in the database 
# (in this case, I have a database named mgmt2go)
# that contain multiple fields (id, date_modified) against which you want to search
CREATE PROCEDURE `mgmt2go`.rc_list_tables_procedure( IN rc_cutoff_date DATETIME )
BEGIN
    # Always DECLARE in sequence: Variables, Cursors, Handler
    # Variables
    DECLARE rc_last_record BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE rc_table_name varchar(64);
    # Cursor
    DECLARE rc_table_list CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT `TABLE_NAME` 
        FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
        WHERE `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS`.`TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'mgmt2go' 
        AND `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS`.`COLUMN_NAME` 
            IN ( 'id' , 'date_modified' ) 
        GROUP BY TABLE_NAME HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT COLUMN_NAME ) = 2 
        ORDER BY `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS`.`TABLE_NAME`;
    # Handler
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET rc_last_record = TRUE;
    # Activate the LOOP
    OPEN rc_table_list;
        rc_for_each_loop: LOOP
            # Test if the previous iteration of the LOOP fetched the last record
            # and if so, exit the LOOP
            FETCH FROM rc_table_list INTO rc_table_name;
            IF rc_last_record = TRUE THEN
                LEAVE rc_for_each_loop;
            END IF;
            # Eliminate the entries in the job_queue table 
            # since they are just temporary system entries
            IF rc_table_name = 'job_queue' THEN
                ITERATE rc_for_each_loop;
            END IF;
            # Find all records in all tables with a date_modified field
            # greater than or equal to the specified value in the CALL
            # We cannot directly use a variable in a SELECT statement
            # So we prepare a SELECT statement by concatenation
            # and then use the Prepare and Execute functions to run the SELECT
            SET @rc_query_for_modified := CONCAT( 
                'SELECT "' , rc_table_name , '" , `id` ,`date_modified` '
                'FROM `mgmt2go`.`' , rc_table_name , '` '
                'WHERE '
                'TIMESTAMP( `mgmt2go`.`' , rc_table_name , '`.`date_modified` )'
                ' >= "' , rc_cutoff_date , '" '
                );
            PREPARE rc_test_modified_statement FROM @rc_query_for_modified;
            EXECUTE rc_test_modified_statement;
            DEALLOCATE PREPARE rc_test_modified_statement;
        END LOOP rc_for_each_loop;
    CLOSE rc_table_list;
END$$

# Reset the delimiter back to the default
DELIMITER ;$$

# Invoke the Procedure, providing the cutoff date = date record more current than
# You can provide an absolute time using
# CALL `mgmt2go`.rc_list_tables_procedure( "2019-01-02 16:49:28" );
# Or you can provide a time n (Seconds/Minutes/...) before a stated time (like NOW()
CALL `mgmt2go`.rc_list_tables_procedure( DATE_SUB( NOW() , INTERVAL 5 MINUTE ) );

# If you are also trying to see if any files have changed in the last n minutes
# and want to NOT search in a particular child directory (/cache in this case)
# at the CLI enter 
# find path_to_directory -path path_to_child_directory_to_exclude -prune , -type f -mmin -120
# or
# find path_to_directory -mmin -120 -iname "*.*" | egrep -v "(child_directory_to_exclude)"
# where -120 is the number of minutes to look back (120 in this case)
# -mmin is minutes since modification and -cmin is minutes since creation
# -mtime is days since modification and -ctime is days since creation
```