# Mysql Select all rows with 10 minute difference

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with timestamp and I want to retrieve all the records with 10 minutes difference between each other.
I give you an example: 
I have in my database 4 dates:

```
01-12-2015 15:45:10
01-12-2015 15:55:10
01-12-2015 15:25:10
01-12-2015 15:15:10
```

I want to retrieve only the 2 dates that have 10 minutes difference between each other.

I don't want to get all records where the timestamp is within 10 minutes of the current timestamp. I want to select all the records having a difference of 10 minutes between them.
So in my example I want to select on the dates:

```
01-12-2015 15:45:10
01-12-2015 15:55:10
```

These 2 dates should have a difference of 10 minutes between them.
How I can do that?

Comment: Show your query please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select all records that are 10 minutes within current timestamp in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9013494/how-to-select-all-records-that-are-10-minutes-within-current-timestamp-in-mysql)

Comment: No it's not duplicate. I don't want to get all records where the timestamp is within 10 minutes of the current timestamp. I want to select all the records having a difference of 10 minutes between them.

Comment: Why doesn't it *look* like a timestamp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch data from sql query and write the logic in your php file as follows:

```
$select =   mysql_query("SELECT your_datetime_column_name as time,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(your_datetime_column_name) as time_string FROM your_table_name");
 $result = mysql_fetch_array($select);
    $final_result= NULL;
    $j=0;
    foreach($result as $ff)
    {
       foreach($result as $ff11)
    {
       if(abs($ff11['time_string'] - $ff['time_string']) ==600 ){ 
       $final_result[$j]['time1']=$ff['time'];
           $final_result[$j]['time2']=$ff11['time'];
       $j++;
        }
    }
    }
```

and in array $final_result you will get all the dates pair with 10 min difference.
hope it will help you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `now()` to get the current time.  So:

```
select t.*
from t
where t >= date_sub(now(), interval 10 minute);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the example how you compute if the two dates has 10 minutes difference in the current time 1st param let say the current time.
`SELECT TIMEDIFF('2015-12-11 08:20:00','2015-12-11 08:10:00')`

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have an index. Make an JOIN on index = index+1 -> Every row is connected with the previous one. Then calculate the time diff and pick only those rows with diff more then 10 minutes.

```
SELECT *
FROM dates AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN dates AS b 
ON a.id = b.id+1
WHERE a.timestamps-b.timestamps >= 600
```

Have a look at this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/31b0eb/3

Comment: My code:
SELECT * FROM stats AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN stats As b ON a.id = b.id+1 WHERE (a.time - b.time) = 100;

But I get the error error SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 1690 BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in '(`panel`.`a`.`time` - `panel`.`b`.`time`)'

Comment: you have to convert your date from string-format into (unix)timestamp format to simply calculate the diff. I think you should have a look at the date time function of MySQL (especially UNIX_TIMESTAMP like in my SQL-Fiddle) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Select * from a where a.id not in
 (select b.id from a b where TIMEstampDIFF(SECOND,a.mydate,b.mydate)<=600)
and a.id not in
 (select c.id from a c where TIMEstampDIFF(SECOND,a.mydate,c.mydate)>600)
```