# How can I select a record from MySQL that is older than 10min?

Tags: mysql

How do I select a record from MySQL that is older than 10min?

Comment: what values are stored in valid field?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select all records that are 10 minutes within current timestamp in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9013494/how-to-select-all-records-that-are-10-minutes-within-current-timestamp-in-mysql)

Comment: What is valid? Is it a datetime field? If yes use this query "SELECT `record` FROM `act_0223` WHERE valid > NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE"

Comment: yes it's a DATETIME field

Answer (score 2):

SELECT `record` FROM `act_0223` WHERE valid < NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE

Comment: @bool, can I get this answer accepted please?