# Insert only the data that does not exist PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a php file that will copy data from one database server to another database server.

my php file:

```
<?php
    require_once 'config.php'; //just a php file for database connection

    try{  
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=sampledb;', 'username', 'password' );
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare(
                "SELECT
                contro_number,name,date_save,date_received
                FROM
                    ETable
                WHERE
                   date_save IS NOT NULL AND date_received >= '2020-01-03'  
                    "
        );
        $stmt->execute();

        while( $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            insert_mysql($row["control_number"],$row["name"],$row["date_save"],$row["date_received"]);
        }
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        var_dump($e->getMessage());
    }
    $pdo = null; 


    function insert_mysql($control_number,$name,$date_save,$date_received)
    {
        try{
            $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost:3306;dbname=secondDB;', '', '' );
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare(
                    "INSERT INTO `MyTable`
                        (`control_number`,`name`,`date_save`,`date_received`)
                    VALUES
                        (:control_number,:name,:date_save,:date_received)
                            "
            );

            $stmt->bindValue( ':control_number', $control_number, PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt->bindValue( ':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt->bindValue( ':date_save', $date_save, PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt->bindValue( ':date_received', $date_received, PDO::PARAM_STR );

            $flag = $stmt->execute();

            if( !$flag ) {
                $info = $stmt->errorInfo();
                exit($info[2]);
            }
            }catch(PDOException $e){
                var_dump($e->getMessage());
            }
            $pdo = null;
        }

    ?>
```

Now, I plan to make this php file runs every 10 minutes using .bat file , to make the inserting of data be automatically.

But, if this file will run repeatedly, data will only be duplicated.

What will be the query or condition that I must do to Filter first the data and check if it already exist, if not then insert the data? So that every time there is a new data in one database it will automatically copy or inserted to another database...

Comment: Use ```upsert``` Mysql query or in query set date in where condition they select only last 10 mins records.

Comment: have you considered replication? Replication filters can limit it to a specific table.

Comment: @HP371 I got your point. What will be the query to select only the last 10 mins records?

Comment: @danblack I didn't consider it yet, but i will check for it.thanks

Comment: @Gelxxxx , https://stackoverflow.com/a/9013604/4781696 this link help you to understand how to get last 10 mins records.

Comment: And yeah if you want to same data on both server then you can use replication

Comment: Just index your table. Then run INSERT IGNORE or INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY. Job done.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are not using an id column in your table it seems. Better to add one for unique identification of rows.

Doing this in php (**is not the best way**) needs checking availability and inserting like

```
select id from yourtable where id= newidFromOtherServer;
```

And based upon the result you shall insert or not.

**Better way** is to create a trigger and use
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html

But this is going to eat up your resources heavily.

Comment: Tried this? Give feedback and shall discuss more.

Answer (score -1):

Add another table in both of your databases called last_sync, after every copy from database A to B store the last ID and check for ID's greater than the previous one.

Let's say last_sync table has saved the last ID which is 350, then you should move the records where ID>350 to the other database. This way it will be easy.

**UPDATE**

While you are coping records from A to B, Also Select id from the table A and in the while loop do something like this

```
while( $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
insert_mysql($row["control_number"],$row["name"],$row["date_save"],$row["date_received"]); 
$lastid=$row["id"];
 }
```

$lastid will be updated everytime and you will have the last id copied so now you have to insert it in the last_sync table and next time put the condition as I told

Comment: I got your point. How can I do the storing of last ID for every copy from database A to B in last_sync table?

Comment: Additionally, even if you store last_id somewhere and compare...you also need to check altered / edited rows for updating into your another server.

Comment: @nnn actually there will be no updating, because the data that will be copied is fixed.

Comment: While you are coping records from A to B, Also Select **id** from the table A and in the while loop do something like this                                                           
while( $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {            insert_mysql($row["control_number"],$row["name"],$row["date_save"],$row["date_received"]); $lastid=$row["id"];
        }